# Memcached Stops working after multiple requests

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim

I have implemented Enyim.caching memcached client for my website on a remote server for Session management. It works fine for 2-3 users but when we increase load to 20+ users, memcached server on remote machine stops working. I am not getting any reply by using "stats" command for memcached server but the service appears working.

1. I am using Enyim.caching client for session management.
2. It is installed as a service on remote machine.
3. I am using below config entries in my web.config.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching"/>
</sectionGroup>

Comment: <enyim.com>
      <memcached>
        <servers>
          <!-- put your own server(s) here-->
           <add address="<server's IP>" port="11211" />
        </servers>
       <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100"
      connectionTimeout="00:10:00" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
     </memcached>
  </enyim.com>

Comment: <sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom" customProvider="MemcachedSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MemcachedSessionProvider" type="MemcachedProviders.Session.SessionStateProvider,MemcachedProviders" dbType="None" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"/>
      </providers></sessionState>